# How is possible to specify multiple servers for LDAPConnection using Unboundid SDK?

Tags: ldap, ldapconnection, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I want to specify multiple servers for LDAPConnection like configuration of LDAP URL for Apache: 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#authldapurl:
`ldap://host1 host2 host3:port/basedn?attribute?scope?filter`.

What is the simplest way to do it?
Is it possible to do it without LDAPConnectionPool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at one of the sub-classes of `com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.ServerSet`.

Comment: Thanks, `com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.FailoverServerSet` is exactly what I looked for!

Comment: Thanks for help in all questions!